# angular 2 with mvc 5 bootstrap a component

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

Our site is an existing MVC site and we are working on adding and replacing some parts with angular 2 components.  We do not have a full angular 2 app to launch, so we are just using bootstrap to launch our components on the pages we want them.

I updated my package.json dependencies from "2.0.0-rc.1" to "~2.2.0" and now have the latest angular 2 files.  I can no longer use import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' and launch my component with: bootstrap(MyCountComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, MyService]);.

Searching it seems to have been updated to import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'; and now I should launch with: platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(MyCountComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, MyService]);

When I do this I'm getting the browser Console error: 
Unhandled Promise rejection: (SystemJS) No NgModule metadata found for 'MyCountComponent'.
Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'MyCountComponent'...

Do I need to convert my components to modules now or is there a new way to bootstrap launch the components without a module?

Here is a code sample.

```
//mycount.ts
import { MyService } from '../../services/my.service';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'
import { MyCountComponent } from './mycount.component';

bootstrap(MyCountComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, MyService]); 


//mycount.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { MyService } from '../../services/my.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'mycount',
    templateUrl: './app/components/mycount/mycount.component.html'
})

export class MyCountComponent {

    constructor(private _myService: MyService) {
    }

    get mycount() {
        return this._myService.mycount;
    }
}

//systemjs.config.js
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',

            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
            '@angular/upgrade/static': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js',

            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

**EDIT**
If I have:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule
    ],
    bootstrap: [MyCountComponent, MyListComponent, MyDetailsComponent],
    declarations: [MyCountComponent, MyListComponent, MyDetailsComponent],
    exports: [MyCountComponent, MyListComponent, MyDetailsComponent],
    providers: [MyService]
})
```

Is it possible for my page to only load 1 or 2 of the components?
I tried calling it with:

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(MyModule, [HttpModule, MyListComponent]);

but I get an error message for any component tags missing from the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create main @NgModule where you can import all Services, Components, Directives etc. using @NgModule you can tell your app that which component should bootstrap.

here is official links to understand that @ngModule please go through this: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

Tips: please use [Angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) which will create a basic structure of app just in few minutes. using Angular-cli you no need to create structued app or basic setup it will do it for you.

Comment: Do I need to create a module for every individual component? Is it possible to have multiple components in a module but only display a single component on a page?  I updated my original post with details.

Comment: yes you can create multiple module, i recommends create modules according to your functionality, like you can create admin module which is admin control panel, you can create client module where client can open their dashboard, public module where every body can see that page example: home page, about us page etc.....[1]

Comment: each modules contain multiple components for example admin module has listUserComponent, editUserComponent, addNewUserComponent. component which are added in admin module those are not available out of the that admin module.....[2]

Comment: yes you can display single component at a time, this depends on your requirement. add, edit, and view user component you can display individual in admin module, they have separate url. also you can display list and edit user in one single component, again it depends on your logic and requirement....